# How to use Icons that come in the format of EPS

Tags: icons, png, frontend, eps

i'm not much of a front end developer but got a set of icons that came in an EPS format...What's the best way to use these fonts on a website? I have a big sprite I'm using but these icons won't convert to png in photoshop... Any thoughts on how to use them???

Comment: Have you tried converting to GIF or JPEG? from what I looked up it seems like EPS cannot be used directly in a website.. actually you can also use SVG format to display in a website

Comment: How come so many icons come in this format??? weird...

Comment: Thank you for the response though

Comment: those icons come from adobe illustrator.. i think thats the format that it generally uses.. but if you want to use it on a website then you have to convert to one of the many forms that the web allows